# Storing a variable in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, file-io, encryption

The problem is that file won't be read...Apparently there's a problem with an array but I don't really know how fix this issue...I'm a beginner to C++ 'arrays' and 'strings'...

My file should read the code, then translate the file, then output the text into a new file..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()    
{    
    // Declarations
    string reply;    
    string inputFileName;

    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    char character;

    cout << "Input file name: ";
    getline(cin, inputFileName);

    // Open the input file.    
    inputFile.open(inputFileName.c_str());

    // Check the file opened successfully.    
    if ( ! inputFile.is_open()) {

        cout << "Unable to open input file." << endl;    
        cout << "Press enter to continue...";

        getline(cin, reply);

        return 1;
    }

    // This section reads and echo's the file one character (byte) at a time.
    while (inputFile.peek() != EOF) {

        inputFile.get(character);

        //cout << character;
      //Don't display the file...

        char cipher[sizeof(character)];

      //Caesar Cipher code...
        int shift;
        do {
            cout << "enter a value between 1-26 to encrypt the text: ";
            cin >> shift;
        } 
        while ((shift <1) || (shift >26));

        int size = strlen(character);
        int i=0;

        for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            cipher[i] = character[i];

            if (islower(cipher[i])) {
                cipher[i] = (cipher[i]-'a'+shift)%26+'a';
            }
            else if (isupper(cipher[i])) {
                cipher[i] = (cipher[i]-'A'+shift)%26+'A';
            }
        }

        cipher[size] = '\0';
        cout << cipher << endl;  
    }

    cout << "\nEnd of file reached\n" << endl;

    // Close the input file stream
    inputFile.close();

    cout << "Press enter to continue...";
    getline(cin, reply);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: "Apparently there's a problem with an array but I don't really know how fix this issue..."  If you're getting error messages you should provide them for us to see.

Comment: You're passing a single char to `strlen` that expects a `const char *` type. Why call strlen on it at all? char is always going to be 1.

Comment: What are you expecting `char cipher[sizeof(character)];` to do exactly?

Comment: Did this code compile?

Comment: @greatwolf I'm expecting to read "whole text" from the file then translate them using Caesar Cipher...

Comment: are you giving the full name+path of the text file that you are opening to the program. It is running on my system.

Comment: @Andrew_CS Thisa re the compile error I get...

texting.cpp:72:32: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

string.h:399:15: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘size_t strlen(const char*)’ [-fpermissive]

texting.cpp:77:32: error: invalid types ‘char[int]’ for array subscript

Comment: @mahi yes I'm giving full name and path for the file to read...

Comment: @greatwolf so I change  'strlen' into 'const char*'

Comment: pixelchemist's answer covers the important bases. It looks like your code is trying to stuff everything into `character` like it's some kind of array. You simply cannot do that since it can only hold *one byte* of information. You're better off using `std::string` instead of `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your code, "character" is declared as a `char` which means it can only store *one byte* of information. Yet later on you start using it as if it was an array of characters.

You are also declare "cipher" as a char array that you manual manage like a string which is error prone. The real issue however is that you're mixing C-like code in C++. In other words, the way your code is written isn't considered idiomatic C++.

Pixelchemist already went over the important points so I'll just present a minimal refactored working example of your above code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    string filename;
    cout << "enter input file: ";
    cin >> filename;

    ifstream inputFile( filename.c_str() );
    string plaintext;
    do
    {
      plaintext += inputFile.get();
    }while(inputFile);
    cout << plaintext << endl;

    string  &ciphertext = plaintext;

    //Caesar Cipher code...
    int shift = rand() % 26 + 1;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ciphertext.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (islower(ciphertext[i])) {
            ciphertext[i] = (ciphertext[i] - 'a' + shift) % 26 + 'a';
        }
        else if (isupper(ciphertext[i])) {
            ciphertext[i] = (ciphertext[i] - 'A' + shift) % 26 + 'A';
        }
    }

    cout << ciphertext << endl;
}
```

You'll notice in the refactor that I've done away with `char` and `char[]` arrays altogether and replaced it with `std::string`. I'm also performing the cipher operation inplace on the plaintext input. This is done by making a reference alias to `plaintext` called `ciphertext` for readability. Also in my example, the shift is done randomly for prototyping but you should change it to take it as a user input instead.

Comment: There's an error in your code with ' cipher ' not being declared...
do you declare ' cipher ' as an 'array' or a 'string' ???

Comment: @user2066703 looks like I missed a copy and paste. whoops! it's fixed now

Comment: hey thanks really for the help...Is just that I'm beginner in C++ so I don't really know the difference between C and C++

Comment: lets say I want to output the 'ciphertext' into a new file... can I still use ** ofstream.open("transcribed.txt") **

Comment: @user2066703 yeah, `ciphertext` is just a string so you can just use `<<` insertion operator to write it to the file stream.

Comment: @greatwolf It's still a mix of C and C++

Answer (score 2):

To make it short: You're on c++ so just don't use the whole C stuff.

- Don't use character arrays, use `std::string`
- Don't use `islower(char)` but use `std::islower(char,locale)`
- Don't use C-style arrays but `std::array` (compile time constant size) or `std::vector` (dynamic size)

You'll want to have it more like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <locale>

int main (void)
{
  std::string input_filename;
  std::cout << "Input file name: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, input_filename);
  unsigned int shift;
  do 
  {
    std::cout << "Enter a value between 1-26 to encrypt the text: ";
    std::cin >> shift;
  } 
  while ((shift == 0) || (shift > 26));
  try
  {
    std::string filestring;
    std::ifstream input(input_filename, std::ios_base::in);
    if (input)
    {
      input.seekg(0, std::ios::end);   
      filestring.reserve(input.tellg());
      input.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
      filestring.assign
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), 
          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    } 
    else
    {
      std::string error_string("Reading failed for: \"");
      error_string.append(input_filename);
      error_string.append("\"");
      throw std::runtime_error(error_string);
    }
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(filestring.size());
    std::locale const loc;
    for (auto character : filestring)
    {
      char const shifter(std::islower(character, loc) ? 'a' : 'A');
      result.push_back((character-shifter+shift)%26+shifter);
    }
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
  }
  catch (std::exception & e)
  {
    std::cout << "Execution failed with an exception: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This solution requires C++11 support. If you do not have C++11 you can replace the loop with:

```
size_t const N(filestring.length());
for (size_t i(0u); i<N; ++i)
{
  char const shifter(std::islower(filestring[i], loc) ? 'a' : 'A');
  result.push_back((filestring[i]-shifter+shift)%26+shifter);
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how and why you used "catch" and "throw"

Comment: 'final.cpp:42:15: error: ‘character’ does not name a type'


'final.cpp:47:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘std’ '


'final.cpp:48:3: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token'




'final.cpp:48:3: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘}’ token'



'final.cpp:48:3: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
'


final.cpp:48:3: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token

Comment: @user2066703 I use try and catch since I throw a `std::runtime_error` if the file does not exists, cannot be opened or another error occurs upon stream initialization. I think the problem may be the range-based for-loop. Do you have C++11 enabled? Which compiler do you use? If you have gcc newer than Version `4.6` try using `-std=c++0x` (or `-std=c++11` since gcc `4.7`).

Comment: So just a quick question @Pixelchemist ....Is it okay to combine C and C++ when writing a code?? or should I just stay with one and never combine....?

Comment: @user2066703 There are problems where you can't get around C (for example lhwn using ibraries written in C) but you should stick to C++ when using C++.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with a single char, thats e.g. just one letter or a number. So the whole thing with size handling is useless, because the size is always 1. You probably should use const char*. But then you can't use filestream.get() at all, because it only returns a single char (not and cstring aka const char*).
And you can use fstream.get() as condition for the loop, so you don't need to ask for the eof flag.

```
    char my_char;
    std::ifstream infstream("filename.txt");
    if(!infstream.isopen())
        return -1;
    while(infstream.get(my_char) {
        //do some stuff
    }
```

or

```
   std::string my_string;
    std::ifstream infstream("filename.txt");
    if(!infstream.isopen())
        return -1;
    while(infstream >> my_string) {
        //do some stuff
    }
```

for dynamic arrays in C++ use std::vector or std::list or ... one of the other STL containers, so you don't have to waste your time on memory management and using static sized arrays.
And std::string is the way to go for strings in C++. It is something similar to the STL containers, but just for char's.

Comment: so how could I fix this issue that is what I'm trying to figured out...I mean your telling to remove one part in order for another to work... but how would I remove filestream.get() ?